# React native animation is not working for the second time

Tags: react-native, mobile

I have used the default "Animated" package with react native for my animations in the application. Animations in the following code is working fine. But when I navigate to another page and come back to this screen the animation is not working. Once the page gets loaded from ground level only it is working again. What could be the reason ? Can someone please help me to sort this out.

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    animation: {
       usernamePostionLeft: new Animated.Value(795),
       passwordPositionLeft: new Animated.Value(905),
       loginPositionTop: new Animated.Value(1402),
       statusPositionTop: new Animated.Value(1542)
    }
  }
  navigateToScreen = link => event => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(link)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const timing = Animated.timing
    Animated.parallel([
       timing(this.state.animation.usernamePostionLeft, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1700
    }),
    timing(this.state.animation.passwordPositionLeft, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 900
    }),
    timing(this.state.animation.loginPositionTop, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 700
    }),
    timing(this.state.animation.statusPositionTop, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 700
    })
  ]).start()
 }
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground 
        source={lem_bg} 
        blurRadius={10}
        style={styles.imageBgContainer}>
        <View style={styles.internalContainer}>
          <Animated.View style={{position: 'relative', top: 
           this.state.animation.usernamePostionLeft, width: '100%'}}>
           <Text style={styles.LEMHeader}>LEM<Text style={styles.followingtext}>mobile</Text></Text>        
          </Animated.View>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
....MORE JSX ARE THERE...
  )
}
```

}

Comment: did you mean that your componentDidMount () is not calling when you navigate back from another page?

Comment: Could be. How to do this when I coming back from another page ?

Comment: componentDidMount () won't call when navigation popBack. You should write a function to run this animation when you came back from another screen. Let me try it

Comment: @Ruchira do you find any solution?? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount()  won't call when you navigate back from another screen. for this, you have to create your own callback method for performing this animation when you pop() from another screen. Consider below code change

first screen

```
  navigateToScreen = link => event => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(link,{
      callback:this.runAnimation
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.runAnimation()
  }

  runAnimation(){
    const timing = Animated.timing
    Animated.parallel([
      timing(this.state.animation.usernamePostionLeft, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1700
      }),
      timing(this.state.animation.passwordPositionLeft, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 900
      }),
      timing(this.state.animation.loginPositionTop, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 700
      }),
      timing(this.state.animation.statusPositionTop, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 700
      })
    ]).start()
  }
```

on the second screen when you pop() navigation to back, call this callback

```
 this.props.navigator.pop()
 this.props.callback()
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I am getting the following error.
undefined is not a function (evaluating _this.props.callBack()') I am using the following package for the navigation.
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
Is it because of this ?

Comment: callback()  .  with small 'b'

Comment: Yep It was my typo. Thanks. Even with the callback() still the issue is same. If you don't mind can you please help to sort this out ?